# Hibernate save, update, and saveOrUpdate

Tags: hibernate

I have an Object called Variable with a name and value field. The name field is the primary key which in Hibernate makes it the "identifier". I want to 1) insert Variable into the database if it is not already there and 2) update Variable in the database if it is already there. How do I do that? I have already looked at the Hibernate documentation and I am confused by it. It goes into lengthy explanations of transient, persistent, and detached state, which I will point out some questions about.

> Transient - an object is transient if it has just been instantiated
>   using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate
>   Session. It has no persistent representation in the database and no
>   identifier value has been assigned. Transient instances will be
>   destroyed by the garbage collector if the application does not hold a
>   reference anymore. Use the Hibernate Session to make an object
>   persistent (and let Hibernate take care of the SQL statements that
>   need to be executed for this transition).

If I instantiate a new Variable Object, that Variable Object is clearly transient since it has been instantiated with the new operator. Now what if I assign it a name (the identifier/primary key property) that is already found in the database? Is it still transient? Technically, it is still not associated with a Hibernate Session yet -- Hibernate has no idea that my Variable Object exists. However, it *does* have an identifier assigned and that identifier does already exist in the database. So which is it.. is it a transient Object at this point or not?

> Persistent - a persistent instance has a representation in the
>   database and an identifier value. It might just have been saved or
>   loaded, however, it is by definition in the scope of a Session.
>   Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent
>   state and synchronize the state with the database when the unit of
>   work completes. Developers do not execute manual UPDATE statements, or
>   DELETE statements when an object should be made transient.

This definition of persistent implies that if I load a Variable Object from the Hibernate Session with `.load(Variable.class, "name")` then that Variable is now persistent since the Session has knowledge of its existence. However it also says that it will "synchronize state with the database when the unit of work completes". When does that happen? Should I call .save() or .update() on a Variable that I have .load()ed from the database after I've made changes to it? Otherwise how should I get the value in the DB to update?

Basically, I read the documentation about [Hibernate - Working with Objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-makingpersistent) but the explanations of persistent and transient state are still unclear, and therefore so are save, update, and saveOrUpdate.

Comment: You pasted the description of transient and persistent, but forgot the description of detached. That's what your object instantiated with new and having an ID is: it has a persistent representation in database, but is not attached to the session.

Comment: @JBNizet The documentation says a Detached object "has been persistent, but its Session has been closed". How could it be Detached if it was never part of a Session to begin with?

Comment: You're right. The documentation assumes that IDs are generated by Hibernate, and that you don't initialize persistent entities from thin air, but always start from either a new entity that you insert, or from a persistent entity that you modify. And that's indeed a good practice to follow.

Comment: @JBNizet I am following good practices. I'm trying to update a database value if it already exists, or insert it if it doesn't exist.  How do I do that with Hibernate? As you can see it's quite difficult to determine the best way to do things, when the language contained in the documentation is ambiguous as I just showed... hence my question on this site...

Comment: The best practice is to let the database (or Hibernate) generate the ID. That way, if you have an ID, you know that the value exists in the database. And if you don't have one, you know it doesn't. If you assign an ID yourself, that means that you want to create a new entity. Else, the data should come from the database, and be a detached entity. If you really want to do what you're about to do, then get the entity and call merge() if it's not-null, and persist() otherwise.

Comment: @JBNizet saveOrUpdate() works, I just tested it. It adds the row to the database if it isn't there and modifies the existing row in the database if it is there. In both cases, I create my new entity by doing new Variable(name, value). IDK why the hibernate documentation is so ambiguous, I still have no idea why it works, or how to answer the above questions about transient vs. persistent.

Comment: It works, yes, but I tend to avoid it, because it doesn't exist in JPA, only works if the entity hasn't been loaded yet, and can lead to situations where attached entities are linked to detached ones, which make it a pain to debug. That's why I prefer using merge().